# Grilling duck - How can I get the fat?

Tags: fat, duck

I'm going to grill a whole duck tomorrow.  I am going to steam the duck before so the fat will render off.  When that's complete, I am going to have a pot full of duck fat and leftover water.

What's the best way to get the fat off?  Refrigerate the water till the fat separates?  Boil the pot until the water evaporates?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Refrigerate it and the fat will get on top of the water.